# how to best approach to use spring batch annotation or xml files ?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

firstly, thanks for attention,in my spring batch project defined many jobs , for example:

```
    <batch:job id="helloWorldJob1" job-repository="jobRepository">
            <batch:step id="step1" >
                <batch:tasklet>
                    <batch:chunk reader="itemReader1" writer="itemWriter1"
                                 processor="itemProcessor1">
                    </batch:chunk>
                </batch:tasklet>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:job>
    <batch:job id="helloWorldJob2" job-repository="jobRepository">
            <batch:step id="step1" >
                <batch:tasklet>
                    <batch:chunk reader="itemReader2" writer="itemWriter2"
                                 processor="itemProcessor2">
                    </batch:chunk>
                </batch:tasklet>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:job>
    <batch:job id="helloWorldJob3" job-repository="jobRepository">
            <batch:step id="step1" >
                <batch:tasklet>
                    <batch:chunk reader="itemReader3" writer="itemWriter3"
                                 processor="itemProcessor3">
                    </batch:chunk>
                </batch:tasklet>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:job>
    .  
    . 
    .   
    .
```

how to use pure annotation ? is it the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically good start is [Spring batch official documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/). Only thing here to note is that example has one job which runs when you do 
`mvn spring-boot:run`. `BatchConfiguration` is example how pure java configuration can look like.

On our project we created main configuration like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing(modular = true)
public class JobContextConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Bean
    public ApplicationContextFactory helloWorldJob1Job() {
        return new GenericApplicationContextFactory(HelloWorldJob1JobConfig.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationContextFactory helloWorldJob2Job() {
        return new GenericApplicationContextFactory(HelloWorldJob2JobConfig.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationContextFactory helloWorldJob3Job() {
        return new GenericApplicationContextFactory(HelloWorldJob3JobConfig.class);
    }        
}
```

And we have separate configuration in separate context for each of jobs. `HelloWorldJob1JobConfig` would hold everything that that job needs and class would look like `BatchConfiguration` from spring example. This will create everything you need except triggering so we created launchers for each job (we are launching some jobs over http, some with messaging and some manually so we needed actually to start jobs defined this way with `JobLauncher`).

Another good resource for integrating `spring-batch` with `spring-boot` with pure java configuration is [spring batch boot web starter](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-starter-batch-web).