# How to create Master Job to process multiple spring batch job?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

We have multiple `spring batch job`.But Each of them needs to be started individually.

Is there any way to create a `Master Job` or `any controller` in spring which will be responsible for executing all  other batch jobs? So that we just have to execute the master job only,and all other started automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just explained on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045837/how-to-best-approach-to-use-spring-batch-annotation-or-xml-files/30048830#30048830) how you can start spring application with all jobs loaded in separate context. We have restart job which is scheduled each 10min and it checks for latest failed execution and attempts to restart couple of more times.

Your use case is pretty much the same, you can define all jobs in separate contexts with own configuration files, in config you can tell spring batch not to run them on startup by setting `spring.batch.job.enabled: false` and you can write your own launcher which uses `JobExplorer` to start jobs for you and you can schedule it or something.

Something like:

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class AllJobLauncher {

    @Autowired
    JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @Autowired
    private JobRegistry jobRegistry;

    @Scheduled(cron = "${some.cron:0 0/10 * * * ?}")
    public void launchAllJobs() throws JobExecutionException {
        final List<String> jobNames = jobExplorer.getJobNames();

        for (final String jobName : jobNames) {
             final Job job = jobRegistry.getJob(getJobName(organizationId));
             final JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder() //build parameters

             jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
         }
    }
```

Just pay attention that `JobLauncher` in spring batch is by default sync so launcher will wait until job finishes. If you want to start jobs async you must place this configuration somewhere:

```
@Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher() {
    final SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    final SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(simpleAsyncTaskExecutor);
    return jobLauncher;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation,just one more point,can we have common JobLauncher and JobRepository for multiple job?

Comment: If you are looking in configuration I posted on other question, this part of `JobLauncher` code I posted here is in `JobContextConfig` class, so we use only one bean of `JobRepository` and `JobLauncher`